# How to create a wordcloud according to frequencies in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, frequency, word-cloud

I have to plot a wordcloud. 'tweets.csv' is a Pandas dataframe which has a column named 'text'. The plotted graph hasn't been based on the most common words, tough. How can the words sizes be linked to their frequencies in dataframe?

```
text = df_final.text.values
wordcloud = WordCloud(
    #mask = logomask,
    max_words = 1000,
    width = 600,
    height = 400,
    #max_font_size = 1000,
    #min_font_size = 100,
    normalize_plurals = True,
    #scale = 5,
    #relative_scaling = 0,
    background_color = 'black',
    stopwords = STOPWORDS.union(stopwords)
).generate(str(text))
fig = plt.figure(
    figsize = (50,40),
    facecolor = 'k',
    edgecolor = 'k')
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation = 'bilinear')
plt.axis('off')
plt.tight_layout(pad=0)
plt.show()
```

My dataframe looks like this:

```
0   RT @Pontifex_pt: Temos que descobrir as riquezezas ...
1   RT @Pontifex_pt: Todos estamos em viagem rumo ...
2   RT @Pontifex_pt: Unamos as forças, em todos ...
3   RT @GeneralMourao: #Segurançapública, preocupa ...
4   RT @FIFAcom: The Brasileirao U-17 final provided ...
```

[image: link to the image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Setup a Sample DataFrame:

- Also see [DataCamp: Generating WordClouds in Python](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/wordcloud-python)
- Package documentation is at [WordCloud for Python documentation](http://amueller.github.io/word_cloud/), [GitHib: wordcloud](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud), and [Anaconda: wordcloud](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/wordcloud)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'word': ['how', 'are', 'you', 'doing', 'this', 'afternoon'],
                   'count': [7, 10, 4, 1, 20, 100]}) 

        word  count
0        how      7
1        are     10
2        you      4
3      doing      1
4       this     20
5  afternoon    100
```

#### Convert the `word` & `count` columns to a `dict`

- `WordCloud().generate_from_frequencies()` requires a `dict`
- Use one of the following methods

```py
# method 1: convert to dict 
data = dict(zip(df['word'].tolist(), df['count'].tolist()))

# method 2: convert to dict
data = df.set_index('word').to_dict()['count']

print(data)

[out]: {'how': 7, 'are': 10, 'you': 4, 'doing': 1, 'this': 20, 'afternoon': 100}
```

### Wordcloud:

- use `.generate_from_frequencies`
- [`generate_from_frequencies(frequencies, max_font_size=None)`](https://amueller.github.io/word_cloud/generated/wordcloud.WordCloud.html#wordcloud.WordCloud.generate_from_frequencies)

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud

wc = WordCloud(width=800, height=400, max_words=200).generate_from_frequencies(data)
```

### Plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.imshow(wc, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]

### Using an image mask:

```
twitter_mask = np.array(Image.open('twitter.png'))
wc = WordCloud(background_color='white', width=800, height=400, max_words=200, mask=twitter_mask).generate_from_frequencies(data_nyt)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.imshow(wc, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(twitter_mask, cmap=plt.cm.gray, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I show it using example,

example:
will-2
freedom-8
ring-3
day-3
dream-5
let-2
every-3
able-2
one-3
together-4

First import necessary libraries,

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Then create our words as a list,

```
text={'will': 2, 'freedom': 8, 'ring': 3, 'day': 3, 'dream': 5, 'let': 2, 'every': 3, 'able': 2, 'one': 3, 'together': 4}
```

Then create wordcloud object,

```
wordcloud = WordCloud(width=800, height=800, margin=0,repeat=True).generate_from_frequencies(text)
```

You must add to **repeat=True** otherwise it is not working.

Then generate image,

```
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")
plt.margins(x=0, y=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]