# Specify amount of Tweets Tweepy returns

Tags: python, pandas, twitter, tweepy, word-cloud

I am building a word cloud from public Tweets. I have connected to the API via Tweepy and have successfully gotten it to return Tweets related to my search term, but for some reason can only get it to return 15 Tweets.

```
import pandas as pd

# subject of word cloud
search_term = 'ENTER SEARCH TERM HERE'

# creating dataframe containing the username and corresponding tweet content relating to our search term
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [tweet.user.id, tweet.user.name, tweet.text] for tweet in api.search(q=search_term, lang="en")
)

# renaming columns of data frame
df.rename(columns={0 : 'user id'}, inplace=True)
df.rename(columns={1 : 'screen name'}, inplace=True)
df.rename(columns={2 : 'text'}, inplace=True)
df
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract data from a Tweepy object into a pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58666135/how-to-extract-data-from-a-tweepy-object-into-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: [How to create a wordcloud according to frequencies in a pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57826063)

Answer (score 0):

By default, the [standard search API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets) that [`API.search`](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html#tweepy.API.search) uses returns up to 15 Tweets per page.
You need to specify the `count` parameter, up to a maximum of 100, if you want to retrieve more per request.

If you want more than 100 or a guaranteed amount, you'll need to look into paginating using [`tweepy.Cursor`](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/pagination.html#tweepy.Cursor).